# want an optimal solution for inserting more than one data in a single column of a single row

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus

```
DROP TABLE District_Info;

CREATE TABLE District_Info(
Dname VARCHAR2(20) primary key,
Boundary_dist VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

for this code, for each Dname there are more than one Boundary_dist. it would be better if i could use an array of varchar2(20) and insert as much boundary_dist as i need to. want some helpful suggestions.

Comment: The common approach in relational databases is "one data, one row", "many data, many rows". You probably need to re-examine the tables structure.

Comment: why must it be 1 column of 1 row?  Why not store 1 boundary_dist per row?  If you MUST, you can try using nested tables, but really think about it first...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned, the ideal way to do this would be to store an additional row for each DName/Boundary_Dist combination. The simplest way to do with a structure this simple is to just change your primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE District_Info(
Dname VARCHAR2(20) primary key,
Boundary_dist VARCHAR2(20) primary key);
```

If you're going to need other data in that table that has a 1:1 correlation to District, you would be better off splitting BoundayDist into a separate table:

```
CREATE TABLE District_Info(
Dname VARCHAR2(20) primary key,
Other_info VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE District_Boundary(
Dname VARCHAR2(20) primary key,
Boundary_dist VARCHAR2(20) primary key);
```

If you really insist on storing more that one value per row, you can use a user-defined datatype:

```
create type varchar_20_list as table of varchar2(20);

CREATE TABLE District_Info(
Dname VARCHAR2(20) primary key,
Boundary_dist varchar_20_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a separate table for Boundary_dist and create a foreign key  which references the District_Info table.

Answer (score -2):

Agreed, it'd be best to have Boundary_dist in a second table and connect them with an ID, but if you must typically what I do is store it as "1,2,3,4,5" that way in the code I can manipulate that pretty easily with PHP using explode or with mysql using IN.